# Generate vector map in local machine

Tags: openstreetmap

I have some enthusiastic people who want to learn more about OSM, so I'm planning to host a demo to my personally hosted server (as it won't be wise be using bandwidth from original host), I have download all PBF, then converted them into XML. And have rendered them in OpenGL/matplotlib and showed them, now I want to render different layers. Like only - roads, landmarks, different features.

And now my server is being overloaded. Half of it's bandwidth is gone. And it's really slow, when a request arrives, it renders and then responds. So is there any way I can render tile-set as vector. And save them. When the request arrives, I'll just respond.

Is there any library, for this - OSM 2 Vector or something like that ?

I just want to render raw, without text or sometime with text.

Here is what I'm rendering :
[image]
[image]

I'm using Python to parse and process and then matplotlib to render and save images. These are really time consuming and not even close to tile sizes, that's why I'm looking for some library, where I can just render tiles, as I like, with as much customization I want.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this is not the type of work to do in something like matplotlib. This is GIS type of work, and for that, you need a proper GIS like QGIS or similar:

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/

If you put the data in a PostGIS database with e.g. [osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql), QGIS should be able to happily handle huge datasets.